# Add string to array

Tags: c#, arrays

I am trying to add a string to an array, I have done a lot of research, and came up with two options but neither work, I get a pop-up and the details make it sound like my array is out of bounds, Both methods are inside my addSpam function.  Any ideas on how to fix either method?

```
namespace HW8_DR
{
    class Tester : Spam_Scanner
    {
        private string[] spam = {"$$$", "Affordable", "Bargain", "Beneficiary", "Best price", "Big bucks",
                                 "Cash", "Cash bonus", "Cashcashcash", "Cents on the dollar", "Cheap", "Check",
                                 "Claims", "Collect", "Compare rates", "Cost", "Credit", "Credit bureaus",
                                 "Discount", "Earn", "Easy terms", "F r e e", "Fast cash", "For just $XXX",
                                 "Hidden assets", "hidden charges", "Income", "Incredible deal", "Insurance",
                                 "Investment", "Loans", "Lowest price", "Million dollars", "Money", "Money back",
                                 "Mortgage", "Mortgage rates", "No cost", "No fees", "One hundred percent free",
                                 "Only $", "Pennies a day", "Price", "Profits", "Pure profit", "Quote", "Refinance",
                                 "Save $", "Save big money", "Save up to", "Serious cash", "Subject to credit",
                                 "They keep your money – no refund!", "Unsecured credit", "Unsecured debt",
                                 "US dollars", "Why pay more?"};
        public static double countSpam = 0;
        public static double wordCount = 0;
        public static string posSpam = "";

        public void tester(string email) 
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < spam.Length-1; i++)
                if(email.Contains(spam[i]))
                {
                    countSpam++;
                    posSpam = string.Concat(posSpam, spam[i], "\r\n\r\n");
                }
            wordCount = email.Split(' ').Length;
        }

        public void addSpam(string spamFlag)
        {
            //attempt 1 to add string to spam array
            Array.Resize(ref spam, spam.Length + 1);
            spam[spam.Length] = spamFlag;

            //attempt 2 to add string to spam array
            string[] temp = new string[spam.Length + 1];
            Array.Copy(spam, temp, spam.Length);
            temp.SetValue(spamFlag, spam.Length);
            Array.Copy(temp, spam, temp.Length);
        }
    }
}`
```

Comment: If you want a variable-length data structure, consider using a `List<string>` instead of an array.

Answer (score 4):

Simple solution: don't use an array! `List<T>` is much better suited for this.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
...
private List<string> spam = {"$$$", "Affordable", "Bargain", "Beneficiary", ... }

...

public void addSpam(string spamFlag)
{
    spam.Add(spamFlag);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

DLeh's answer is best - this is what a `List<T>` is for, so that's your solution.

But the reason things are failing for you is that you're attempting to access an index that is one higher than the max index of the array. The highest index is always one less than the length, because arrays are zero-based.

```
int[] arr = new[] { 1, 2, 3 };
Console.WriteLine(arr.Length); // 3
Console.WriteLine(arr[0]); // 1
Console.WriteLine(arr[1]); // 2
Console.WriteLine(arr[2]); // 3
Console.WriteLine(arr[3]); // Exception
```

To access the last item in an array, you either need to use:

```
var lastItem = arr[arr.Length - 1];
// or
var lastItem = arr[arr.GetUpperBound(0)];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Array.Resize(ref spam, spam.Length + 1);
spam[spam.Length] = spamFlag;
```

Here you're trying to write to index `58` (`spam.Length` after the re-size) of a 58-element zero-indexed array; that is, it goes from `0` to `57`.

You should use:

```
Array.Resize(ref spam, spam.Length + 1);
spam[spam.Length - 1] = spamFlag;
```

That said, you should really use `List<string>` instead. Among other things it does the resizing of the internal array it uses in batches rather than on every `Add()`, which makes things much more efficient, as well as being easier.

If you really need an array for some reason, then use `List<string>` for most of the work, and then call `ToArray()` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

While DLeh raise legit points about how it's better to use a List that dynamically grows, and Joe's answer provides a great explanation, I want to add on to a few more things.

Firstly, to *Answer your question*, to fix either method, you probably wanted to do `spam[spam.Length-1] = spamFlag` instead of `spam[spam.Length] = spamFlag` in attempt one. Because indexes start at 0 and the last index within the bound is thus length -1 (As Joe pointed out)

Your second attempt will not work as an **exception is thrown if either array is too short**. See this [dotnetPerl link on the explanation](http://www.dotnetperls.com/array-copy). Basically it isn't recommended to use Array.Copy as you have to ensure the types and lengths are the same as well.

To elaborate on `Array.Resize()`, it should be noted that it's actually a misnomer in which C# doesn't actually *resize* the array. Rather, it creates a new array and copies the contents over. It always does this unless an exception is thrown, so from a performance point of view this is discouraged. (You could have a variable to keep track of how full your array is, and always grow it by double the amount, this avoids you from having to always create a new array.)

This is also used in hashtables as well where if a certain bucket is full, we grow it and rehash everything back in (it's a really fast lookup table/data structure).

Read this  [DotNetPerl tutorial on Array Resize](http://www.dotnetperls.com/array-resize)

However, a lot of times a List is better, but of course there may be a reason why you don't want to/can't use. I know of a few classes that explicitly tell us not to use built in data structures to learn how arrays work.